# YouTube video won't stop on tab activity in android studio

Tags: android

I created an app with four tabs, Home, Video Channel, Facebook Page and About Us. In video channel tab and Facebook page I used Web View...I choose video channel tab and played some videos, but when I select Facebook page tab, the video in video channel tab did not stop. How to correct this bug? Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsM95.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use `webview.pause()` in fragement  onPause method

Comment: `
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        
        webView.pause();
        super.onDetach();
    }`